# How to pass state between routes in NEXT JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a data inside an object in my page. I want to redirect from that page to another page along with the data like the code below

```
const redirectAppointmentStep1 = (value) => {
    router.push({
      pathname: '/Appointment/bookingstep1',
      query: {value : value},
    })
  }
```

and I received that data in `bookingstep1` page like this

```
 const {query} = useRouter()
```

but the problem is the query appear on the url and the url does not look clean. How can I send the data from one page to another page but without appearing it on the url?

I am new in Next.js so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to send "route state" you have to do it via query string, but you can actually "mask" the path that is shown in the browser via the `as` property.

[Router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush)

> ```
> router.push(url, as, options)
> ```
>
> `as` - Optional decorator for the URL that will be shown in the
> browser.

You can decorate the URL to match the path name.

```
const redirectAppointmentStep1 = (value) => {
  router.push(
    {
      pathname: '/Appointment/bookingstep1',
      query: {value : value},
    },
    '/Appointment/bookingstep1', // "as" argument
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the asnwer but my url still appears like this http://localhost:3010/Appointment/bookingstep1?value=child+specialist
is it possible that url only shows like this-> http://localhost:3010/Appointment/bookingstep1

Comment: `as` needs to be passed in the second parameter in `router.push`, not inside the URL object.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks, I was wondering about this as the docs are a little ambiguous on syntax and available properties between the two usage signatures.

Comment: @DrewReese, ty so much your method is working fine but i am getting one issue now, once i refresh the page, data inside query disappears.can you help me on this issue too? i will be grateful

Comment: @UmarAbbas Yes, unfortunately "route state" only persists *during* the route transition. You will want to persist it in the receiving component, i.e. into local component state persisted/initialized from localStorage for example.

Comment: Does the `as` decorator work in Next 14. I am using Nextjs `14.1.0` and using the `as` decorator will navigate to a new route with a clean browser url. But the data sored in query String is lost, i.e I get null when extracting eith `useSearchParams` hook

Comment: @haneSmitter I think so, it appears the `as` decorator still exists in Next.js 14, but only in the "pages" router. See [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerpush).