# Pass additional data to next router in router.push

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Is it possible in next/router to pass some additional data to the next route with `router.push`?

For example,

```
router.push('/my-route', {
    custom: {
       displayError: true
    }
});
```

Obviously, I added that `custom`, but that's the behaviour I want.

Comment: I think only the options specified on [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) can be configured or passed using router.push. For other data-passing scenarios, you are better off with `React-context`, Redux and my recent favorite `jotai`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to pass state between routes in NEXT JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513773/how-to-pass-state-between-routes-in-next-js)? That's not possible with `next/router`, but you can use the query string to pass values.