# Is there anyway to pass state to getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to next.js. I want to pass page state to getServerSideProps. Is it possible to do this?

```html
const Discover = (props) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [discoverResults, setDiscoverResults] = useState(props.data.results);

  // console.log(discoverResults, page);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card items={discoverResults} render={(discoverResults) => <DiscoverCard results={discoverResults} />} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Discover;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const movieData = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MOVIE_DB_KEY}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate`);

  return {
    props: {
      data: movieData.data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: I think you can use [shallow-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) in nextjs , set your page as  params in url and change your route

Comment: @MohsenMahoski Sorry, I'm not sure if I got you. Can you please elaborate?
since every time i press a button ( which is not present right now  ) the page number goes up )

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to pass state between routes in NEXT JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513773/how-to-pass-state-between-routes-in-next-js)? You'll need to re-route to the page and pass the `page` value as a query parameter.

Comment: I don't see why you have to re-route.  The OP is not trying to pass state in the URI, he's trying to set it in a component.

Answer (score 2):

the only way is changing your route with params and recive it in server side :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Discover = (props) => {
  const { page } = props;
  const router = useRouter();

  const goToNextPage = () => {
    router.replace(`/your-page-pathname?page=${+page + 1}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      page is : {page}
      <button onClick={goToNextPage}>
        next page
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Discover;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const  { page } = context.query;
  return {
    props: {
      page: page || 0,
    },
  };
}
```

To read more on the topic, recommend reading: [Refreshing Server-Side Props](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/nextjs/refreshing-server-side-props/)

Comment: use `router.replace` because it doesn't add an item to the history stack

Comment: yes, you're right :) @MhdLouayAl-osh

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use SWR for handling this kind of api calls

an example of this here:
https://swr.vercel.app/examples/ssr

In this example, it can be seen that the api calls happens in the Server side and it is being cached in the Client side.

For handling the query from the urls. This can be done using the same methods as well following the examples from their documentation of SWR https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#pagination

SWR will help alot of stuffs in the api state management. I really recommend to start learning it as soon as possible..